# work on all <span> at the current <div> then check for the value of an attribute of the <span>

Tags: javascript, attributes, nodes, greasemonkey, selectors-api

i am kinda stuck with my javascript, I am making a greasemonkey script for a site, that restricts me to use plain-old javascript only. For now, my script currently does is, search for all the tables, and table row with `ProjectTable-row` then for each `ProjectTable-row` look for a `div` with `ProjectTable-status`, if that `div` **is not found, it will delete the whole row**.

it works great.

```
document.getElementById("gmSomeID").onclick = function showAlert() {
    console.log('invoked');
    var projectDescriptions = document.querySelectorAll('tr.ProjectTable-row'),
        projectDescriptions = Array.prototype.slice.call(projectDescriptions); 
    projectDescriptions.forEach(function(el) { 
        if (el.querySelector('div.ProjectTable-status')) {
        } else {
             el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    });
}
```

but, now I do not know how to work on the current `div` and loop on all `span` inside it. I am still 2 steps short.

1. Loop on all `span`
2. Search for all `span` which contains `data-content="apple"` if none of the `span` has this attribute, then delete it.

Something like this:

For a HTML tag like this:

```
<div class="ProjectTable-status">
    <span data-content="apple">
    </span>
</div>
```

this will not be deleted `data-content` is `apple`.

For a HTML tag like this:

```
<div class="ProjectTable-status">
    <span data-content="banana">
    </span>
</div>
```

this will be deleted, no span has `data-content="apple"`.

For HTML code like this:

```
<div class="ProjectTable-status">
    <span data-content="banana"></span>
    <span data-content="apple"></span>
</div>
```

this will NOT be deleted, the `div` contains at least 1 `span` that has `data-content` of `apple`.

I have no idea, how to proceed now and really tired or trying anything, i do not even know how to check for attribute value.

Hope someone can guide or put me at the right path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with what you provided, I've just slightly refactored it to check for an "apple" span within each div as it loops through. Using continue, we can execute the next iteration of the loop without deleting the div element if we find that it contains an "apple" span. This code is not tested, but just what came off the top of my head, so it might need some tweaking.

```
document.getElementById("gmSomeID").onclick = function showAlert() {
console.log('invoked');
var projectDescriptions = document.querySelectorAll('tr.ProjectTable-row'),
    projectDescriptions = Array.prototype.slice.call(projectDescriptions);
//pointer to work with current div 
var currentDiv;
projectDescriptions.forEach(function(el) { 
    currentDiv = el.querySelector('div.ProjectTable-status');
    //do we have a div?
    if (currentDiv) {
        //look for an apple within the div
        if(currentDiv.querySelector('span[data-content="apple"]')){
             //go to the next iteration of the loop without delete
             continue;
        }
    } 
    //if we made it this far, we didn't find an apple
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);            
});
```

};